# Can most 3 dimensional hyperbolic orbifolds with finite volume be covered by a hyperbolic manifold? 

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

If G is a discrete cofinite volume subgroup of PSL(2,C),then G acts on H3, H3/G is a 3-dim hyperbolic orbifold N with finite volume, my question is : Is it right in most situations that we can find a hyperbolic 3 manifold M as a finite covering space of N?
This question is equivalent to the following :
do most dicrete cofinte volume klein groups have a finit order torsion free subgroup?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is true for all of them. Any finitely generated matrix group has a torsion-free subgroup of finite index; this is the so-called "Selberg's lemma". A canonical source is Ratcliffe's Hyperbolic Manifolds book (you can probably find the relevant section on google books for free, or on gigapedia.com if you are so inclined).

Comment: gigapedia is now library.nu

Comment: gigapedia.com still works fine for me :)